# Ruby Object Model clarification

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

In Ruby, I can write,

```
Dog = Class.new
```

so here, `Dog` is an `Object` which is an instance of `Class`.

Also, I can write

```
fido = Dog.new
```

which is possible only if `Dog` is a `Class`.

Is `Dog` here a `Class` or an `Object`?

Comment: It's an object of class `Class`. So, it's a class. :)

Comment: then why does Dog.superclass produces Object ?

Comment: Because classes are objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything in ruby is an `Object` (except for blocks). And `Dog` here is also a `Class`.

```
Dog = Class.new
fido = Dog.new
```

So the answer is: **both**.

Comment: Still cant digest how can a thing be both a Class and an Object at the same time, do i need to assume that way or is there a resource i can refer for more reasoning ?

Comment: @nik: Nearly *everything* -- even a Class -- is an Object.

Comment: @nik: Dogs are mammals. Fido is a dog. So, it's both a canine and a mammal. Different levels of hierarchy.

Comment: Every time you create something it's an instance of the class. If you take a class `Class` and create an instance of it, you will have a `Class` object (instance of a `Class`). Just like with your `Dog` class, when you create an instance of it, you have an instance of a `Dog` object.

Answer (score 5):

Ask the object itself, to know where they belongs to, like below:

```
Dog = Class.new
fido = Dog.new
Dog.instance_of? Class #=> true
fido.instance_of? Class #=> false
fido.instance_of? Dog #=> true
Dog.superclass #=> Object
Dog.is_a? Object #=> true
Dog.is_a? Class #=> true
```

To look into in more detail see the [`Object model Documentation`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Class.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are making a mistake that some beginners repeatedly do. You are confusing the **two meanings** of "is":

- A is an **instance** of B, and
- A is a **subclass** of B.

With your case,

- `Dog` is an **instance** of (but not a subclass of) `Class`, and
- `Dog` is a **subclass** of (but not an instance of) `Object`.

So, in different senses, it is a `Class` and is an `Object`.

When they say "everything in Ruby is an `Object`", it does not mean that everything is an instance of `Object`. It means that everything is an instance of a (reflexive) subclass of `Object`.

Comment: Note: LSP pretty much demands that "is a **subclass** of B" be indistinguishable from "is an **instance** of B", at least from the point of view of anyone expecting B.  All objects are instances of `Object` as well as of their specific type, as well as of every class along the inheritance chain.  That's why `instance_of?` and `is_a?` return true where subclasses are concerned.

Comment: instance_of? does not consider subclasses. kind_of? does.

Comment: Oops.  I haven't messed with Ruby in a while, and apparently  misread Priti's example.  :P  Your second meaning for "is" doesn't seem to work, though.  Say `Dog` is a subclass of `Mammal`.  Regardless of that relationship, "`Dog` is a Mammal" is incorrect.  `rover`, however, being an *instance* of `Dog`, is a Dog, a Mammal, *and* an Object.  `Dog` is likewise a Class *and* an Object, due to `Class` extending `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

First, install 'y_support' by typing `gem install y_support` in your command prompt. Then, in irb:

```
require 'y_support/name_magic'

class Animal
  include NameMagic
end # You have created a new class
Animal.name #=> "Animal" -- the class is named Animal
class Dog < Animal
  def speak; puts "Bow wow!" end
end #=> hereby, you have created a subclass of Animal class
Cat = Class.new( Animal ) do
  def speak; puts "Meow!" end
end #=> this is another way of creating a subclass
Dog.name #=> "Dog" -- this is a class named Dog
```

And now

```
Fido = Dog.new      #=> You have created a new Dog instance
Dog.instance_names  #=> [:Fido] -- the instance is named Fido
Stripes = Cat.new   #=> You have created a new Cat instance
Cat.instance_names  #=> [:Stripes] -- the instance is named Cat
Animal.instances.size #=> 2 -- we have 2 animals thus far
Animal.instances.each do |animal| animal.speak end #=> Bow wow! Meow!
```

Let's create another dog:

```
Spot = Dog.new      #=> Another Dog instance
Dog.instances.size  #=> 2 -- we now have 2 dogs
Fido.class          #=> Dog -- Fido is an instance of class Dog
Spot.class          #=> Dog -- Spot is also an instance of class Dog
Fido.class.ancestors #=> The output shows you that Fido is also an Animal
Animal.instances.size #=> 3 -- together, we have 3 animals
Animal.instance_names #=> [:Fido, :Stripes, :Spot]
Animal.instance( :Fido ).speak #=> Bow wow!
Animal.instances.each &:speak #=> Bow wow! Meow! Bow wow!
```

Understood? Remember, in Ruby, never work without `NameMagic`.